# Laptop battery capacity reduced to 85%

Tags: dell, laptop, battery

I have a Dell Inspiron 5521 and have Ubuntu 13.10 on it. I noticed that my battery capacity reduced to 85.2%. Is there a solution for this?
Thanks, Leo.

Comment: can you run this command and post the results please ---  upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

Answer (score 2):

Since when?

If this is something that has always been the case in Ubuntu it could be that your have a wear-limiting feature enabled in your BIOS. Our Samsung laptop does this and we only get 80% of battery (but it *has* lasted 3 years without much drop in overall performance).

If the capacity is slowly dropping off, it could be that it's just losing capacity. This still happens with batteries; they have a lifespan where they slowly become less effective at holding charge.

And then there's the possibility it's a bug in the software that's reading the max charge and current charge. You can look at the rawer numbers with:

```
less /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state
```

If they don't correlate with what you know about the battery (it should have its capacity printed on the battery - you might have to take it out to see it), that might be your problem.